# Parts of screen displaying old graphics

Tags: xorg, xfce, graphic-card

I need help with determining what is the reason of graphical artifacts.
Randomly screen changes to the image from screensaver or some previous state of screen (i.e. from half an hour ago), and moving mouse causes it to refresh certain areas when typing text or moving window or hovering clock.
I can make a screenshot and those artifacts are on it:

[image]

and another one:

[image]

So far I've tried:

- testing RAM (nothing faulty found)
- going through Xorg.log (also nothing fishy there)
- dmesg (also nothing when problem is occuring)

My hardware is IBM T60 laptop running Slackware-current. My window manager is XFCE.
`lspci -nn` outputs following card:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV515/M54 [Mobility Radeon X1400] [1002:7145]
```

My entire Xorg.log can be viewed here: https://pastebin.com/PBcKQvp1

`dmesg | egrep 'drm|radeon'` can be viewed here: https://pastebin.com/uTAP3zMZ

Another requested info:

```
# lspci -nnk | grep "VGA\|'Kern'\|3D\|Display" -A2
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV515/M54 [Mobility Radeon X1400] [1002:7145]
        Subsystem: Lenovo Thinkpad T60 model 2007 [17aa:2006]
        Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

Also I've noticed that the problems seems to intensify after running Firefox or Chrome, and closing them results in no artifacts at all (I've tried to induce the problem without a browser running and did not manage to observe any problems).

Did anyone encountered a similar problem and what were possible solutions? Is it a faulty graphic card? Where should I look at next to isolate the problem?

Comment: Please indicate graphics card (`lspci -nn`, pick lines that apply) and driver used (`Xorg.log`) in your question. It can have lots of reasons and will be difficult to debug.

Comment: @dirkt Filled in additional info about hardware, logs and problem intensification while running browser.

Comment: Ok, next step is to try to figure out if the problem occurs in GL (accelerated/3D) or normal (2D) use. Instead of the browser, try running `glxgears`, games that use OpenGL etc., and see if that produces artifacts. If yes, look at the installed libraries for GL and see if you can upgrade them.

Comment: You could also check if this happens with the current version of a different distribution. Debian comes to mind - the stable release just happened recently.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: I've been using ubuntu previously and didn't encounter such problem. Also I don't want to reinstall system to check this. Probably there are less invasive methods?

Comment: `dmesg | egrep 'drm|radeon'`

Comment: @Bahamut: Added https://pastebin.com/uTAP3zMZ to question

Comment: Looks like the [palinopsia bug](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/123756/how-to-mitigate-risk-of-x11-buffer-ghosting-palinopsia-bug). Your video memory is not zeroed and shows old content. This bug affects all graphics drivers I'm aware of. It is quite old and no one fixes it.

Comment: @mviereck: Seems a bit different, because if I am not doing anything, then no parts of screen got refreshed (except clock which refreshes itself every minute). There should be some action with for example textbox on page, and still then only textbox with cursor is being displayed properly, and rest of page with entire screen as well are obfuscated with image from xscreensaver (most of cases).
Also it happens so often, that i cannot use my laptop when it does. Like 5-6 times a minute until I shut down firefox, and then it is ok.

Comment: @mvireck: Added another screenshot: http://oi67.tinypic.com/r7ud51.jpg

Comment: @DevilaN A reinstallation should not be necessary. It's possible to dual boot. And if you don't want to do that, live CDs are also an option. I suspect a virtual machine won't be sufficiently close to the real thing in this context.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with ATI cards, but isn't the radeon driver the free one? If so, give the proprietary one a try.

Comment: Can you show `lspci -nnk | grep "VGA\|'Kern'\|3D\|Display" -A2`  if radeon is bound to your card. It looks for me as a framebuffer modul is load.

Comment: @Bahamut: I've got following info from this command:
# lspci -nnk | grep "VGA\|'Kern'\|3D\|Display" -A2
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV515/M54 [Mobility Radeon X1400] [1002:7145]
        Subsystem: Lenovo Thinkpad T60 model 2007 [17aa:2006]
        Kernel driver in use: radeon

Comment: It seems like it might be a memory issue. Browsers are very much heavy hitters when it comes to memory use, and especially if you have tabs open. If memory is low, then you will have apps hanging because they are blocked, and will not update the screen until something which has more access to resources can activate the graphics to refresh.

Comment: @DevilaN Did you manage to find a solution to that problem? I'm thinking mine could be related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730943/weird-artifacts-on-thinkpad-t60-mobility-radeon-x1400

Comment: @jeanluc162: unfortunately no and I don't own this very machine anymore :(

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a driver bug.  The easiest way to tell would be to test with known good driver (which unfortunately means Windows).